# Error While Post in Angular as (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED )

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express

I am new to Nodejs. Created a API on local server using Mysql. working on Angular as frontend and using Nodejs and Express as backend. But my Angular app can not connect to Node API. in Angular error occurred as:

`POST http://localhost:3000/Auth/signUp net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.`

and on Node console error occured as :

```
Error
    D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
          throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors

ReferenceError: error is not defined[enter image description here][1]
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\Models\model.js:16:25)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Angular\EMSexpress\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**model.js File**

```
 // import db from "../db.js";
 var db = require("../db")
 let model = {
    signup: (input, cb) => { 
       let today = new Date();
       let data = {
       organisationName: input.organisationName,
        email: input.email,
      mobileNumber: input.mobileNumber,
       password: input.password,
       is_Active: 1,
        createdAt: today
      }
       return db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?' ,[data],(err,result)=>{
             console.log("Error");
             console.log(error);
             console.log("result");
             console.log(result);
          })`enter code here`
           },
      findOne: (organisationName,cb) => {
         return db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE organisationName=? AND is_Active=1", 
     [organisationName],cb);
      },
     findMobile: (mobileNumber,cb) => {
          return db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mobileNumber=? AND is_Active=1", 
     [mobileNumber],cb);
     }
    }
        module.exports = model;`
```

**db.js File**

```
 [const mysql = require("mysql")
 const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"localhost",
  port:3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: "123456",
  database: "EMS"
})
 connection.connect(function(err){
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log("mysql connected")
})

  module.exports = connection;][1]`
```

**Router File Auth.js**

```
    var express = require("express")
    var router = express.Router()`enter code here`
    var user = require("../Models/model")
    var bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

    router.get('/signUp', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({Name: 'Naveen'});
 });

    router.post('/signUp', (req, res) => {
    user.signup(req.body, (error, result) => {
    res.json({data: result, error: error })
})
})
module.exports = router;
```

**Angular Service Code**

```
url = `${environment.apiUrl}/Auth`;
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'contentType': 'application/json'
    })
  }
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  signUp(userForm: User) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/signUp`, userForm, this.httpOptions)}
```

**Angular Environment Code**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

**Angular Component Form submit code**

```
onSignup() {
this.userForm = this.registerForm.value;
console.log(this.userForm)
this._signupService.signUp(this.userForm).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
}),
err => {console.log(err)}
this.registerForm.reset();
this.pwdstatus="";

}
```

Comment: My guess is watch your backend, error has a high probability of coming from there, 1)try your query manually to see if is it actually ok 2)watch for your api function - higher chance errors are in post function , watch out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error description your problem is in the following line

```
return db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?' ,[data],(err,result)=>{
                 console.log("Error");
                 console.log(error); // here error is not defined
                 console.log("result");
                 console.log(result);
              })
```

Please rewrite this line according to the following

```
return db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?' ,[data],(err,result)=>{
                 console.log("Error");
                 console.log(err);
                 console.log("result");
                 console.log(result);
              })
```

The error is happening because you named the error param as `err` in the callback function

Comment: Thanks Brother. now it tells everything about my Error.